# video formats: .3gp to .wmv converter

Tags: video, conversion, file-format, wmv, 3gp

preferably free, either a program or online conversion

Answer (score 3):

I've use this website before http://media-convert.com/. Its pretty quick and the video quality seems good.

Comment: http://www.clipconverter.cc/ is also a good choice

Answer (score 2):

You could try [VLC](http://videolan.org).  It will play most file formats and can encode to WMV as well.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows I always used [Super ©](http://erightsoft.podzone.net/GetFile.php?SUPERsetup.exe). According to eRightSoft's [website](http://www.erightsoft.com/Superdc.html) it supports the following input sources:

- Input Image Sequence: jpg, pgm, png, ppm (with sequentially numbered-ONLY filenames)
  having the same filename numbered-ONLY format. Example: 0001.jpg --up to--> 0999.jpg
  note that this format will NOT work name_0001.jpg --up to--> name_0999.jpg  (take out name_)
- Input Video format: 3gp, 3g2, amv, asf, avi, dat, dvr-ms, fli, flc, flv, m2ts, mpg, mkv, mov
  m4v, mp4, nsv, ogm, qt, rm(vb), str, swf, ts, trp, ty, ty+, tmf, viv, vob, wmv ..
- Input Audio format: aac, ac3, amr, flac, mmf, m4a, mp2, mp3, mpc, ogg, ra, wav, wma ..
- Input AviSynth Script Files: avs.   To write a script and specify advanced encoding commands using AviSynth scripts!

For Mac OS X I use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

Both applications are free to use.

Answer (score 0):

As Nuno Curado suggestioned, use [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html). I think is the best. But you must have the lastest codecs in your computer to be able to convert to some filetypes. Then download  K-Lite Mega Codec Pack.